# KeyNotFoundException when it exists

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary

I'm getting the first key in a dictionary and comparing it with a lookup value. They are the same, but when I try to access the key from the dictionary I get a `KeyNotFoundException`:

```
    public void Draw(Graphics graphics, Shape shape)
    {
        foreach (var line in shape.Lines)
        {
            var tuple = shape.LinesToNurmalDictionary.Keys.First();

            bool equals = tuple == line;
            bool referenceEquals = ReferenceEquals(tuple, line);

            var invisible = shape.LinesToNurmalDictionary[line].All(x => x.Z < 0);
```

How can I fix it?

[image: picture]

Added:
Dictionary is

```
Dictionary<Tuple<ShapePoint, ShapePoint>, List<ShapePoint>> LinesToNurmalDictionary;
```

### where ShapePoint is a class

So i 'solved' my problem by using my own class instead of Tuple, but actualy question still unresponsed:

```
public class Line
{
    public ShapePoint A { get; set; }
    public ShapePoint B { get; set; }

    public List<ShapePoint> Normals { get; set; }

    public Line(ShapePoint a, ShapePoint b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        Normals = new List<ShapePoint>();
    }

    private sealed class DefaultEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Line>
    {
        public bool Equals(Line x, Line y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
                return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;
            if (x.GetType() != y.GetType())
                return false;
            return Equals(x.A, y.A) && Equals(x.B, y.B);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Line obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return ((obj.A != null ? obj.A.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ (obj.B != null ? obj.B.GetHashCode() : 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static readonly IEqualityComparer<Line> DefaultComparerInstance = new DefaultEqualityComparer();

    public static IEqualityComparer<Line> DefaultComparer
    {
        get
        {
            return DefaultComparerInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you override Equals, GetHashCode etc in your line type?

Comment: It's Tuple<reftype,reftype>

Comment: Any chance another thread could remove that key between the call to `First()` and the indexer access?

Comment: It's WinForm app (you can see, i'm drawing using Graphics class), so it's [STAThread] and i didn't create any additional threads/tasks/etc

Comment: Try changing to `var invisible = shape.LinesToNurmalDictionary[tuple].All(x => x.Z < 0);` maybe using the loop iterator as a key is causing this behavior.

Comment: @Alex By the way when replying to comments please use `@` to notify.

Comment: My guess is that ShapePoint is mutable and it got changed after added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tia already said in a comment, this happens because an entry is first added to the `Dictionary<,>` where the hash code of the key (here the `Tuple<ShapePoint, ShapePoint>`) has some value which is "saved" and kept by the `Dictionary<,>`. After that the key object is "mutated" (modified) in a way that changes its hash code. This leads to the `Dictionary<,>` being in a corrupt state.

Therefore when the key is searched for afterwards, it is not found. Its "new" hash code differs from the hash the `Dictionary<,>` thinks this key has.

Do not modify objects that might be keys in a `Dictionary<,>` (or members of a `HashSet<>` and so on) in a way that changes their hash codes.

---

Here's an example illustrating. The type:

```
class Changeable
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Prop;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Changeable);
    }
    public bool Equals(Changeable other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return GetType() == other.GetType() && Prop == other.Prop;
    }
}
```

The code that gives the same problem:

```
var onlyInstance = new Changeable();

var dict = new Dictionary<Changeable, string>();

onlyInstance.Prop = 1;
dict.Add(onlyInstance, "what-ever");

onlyInstance.Prop = 2;
string restoredValue = dict[onlyInstance]; // throws!
```